# Understanding the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the scheme $X = \mathbb{P}_k^1$. In Section 14.1 of Vakil's FOAG, he defines the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on $X$ using "transition functions". But here is some questions I can't answer to myself.

(1) As shown there, the global section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ amounts to a polynomial $f(x_{1/0}) \in k[x_{1/0}]$ with degree at most 1 (the polynomial $g(x_{0/1})$ is then determined by $f$ and hence is completely redundant), and there is nothing special about 1, so one can generalize this argument to any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so a global section of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ amounts to a polynomial with degree at most $n$. If $n \geq 0$, is it true that the ring of global section of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ the same thing as (or more precisely, naturally identified with) the $k$-module $k[x_{1/0}] / (x_{1/0}^{n+1}-1)$? If not, what would the module structure looks like? But in any case, it should also be identifiable by the degree-$n$ bit of $k[x,y]$ (as Vakil claimed after Exercise 14.1.B) via homogenization.

(2) For $n > 0$, there is no nonzero global section of $\mathcal{O}(-n)$. Vakil also gives another obvious meaning for $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ as $(\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes n})^\vee = \mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{O}(n), \mathcal{O}_X)$. But then the global section of the latter invertible sheaf is just (by definition of sheaf Hom) $\hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}(n), \mathcal{O}_X)$. Why is this a singleton?

Now consider the scheme $Y = \mathbb{P}_k^m$.

(3) In Exercise 14.1.C, Vakil says the dimension of the global section of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is $\binom{m+n}{m}$. I tried to do this by generalizing the argument used with $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ but not sure whether it is correct. A global section amounts to an $(m+1)$-tuple of polynomials $(f_0, \cdots, f_m)$, with $f_i \in k[x_{0/i}, \cdots, \widehat{x_{i/i}}, \cdots, x_{m/i}]$, such that
$$f_i(x_{0/j}x_{i/j}^{-1}, \cdots, x_{m/j} x_{i/j}^{-1} ) x_{i/j}^n = f_j(x_{0/j}, \cdots, x_{m/j})$$
for all $i,j$. A little (or a lot of) thought will show that in order for the LHS to be a polynomial, the total degree of any monomial in $f_i$ cannot exceed $n$, and there are $\binom{m+n}{m}$ such monomials  (using some elementary combinatorial argument). Then we can determine the $(m+1)$-tuple of polynomials with any one of $f_i$ with the formula above, and hence the dimension is $\binom{m+n}{m}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer below I often identify $x_{j/i}$ with $x_j/x_i$.

(1) The global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ is a pair $f(x_{0/1}) \in \mathcal{O}_X(n)(D_+(x_0))$ and $g(x_{0/1}) \in \mathcal{O}_X(n)(D_+(x_1))$ such that their restriction on $D_+(x_0) \cap D_+(x_1)$ is equal.

Note that $O_X(n)(D_+(x_0)) = k[x_{1/0}] \cdot x_0^n/1$ and $O_X(n)(D_+(x_0)) = k[x_{0/1}] \cdot x_1^n/1$, let $f = F(x_0,x_1)/x_0^d \cdot x_0^n/1 \in \mathcal{O}_X(n)(D_+(x_0))$ and $g = G(x_0,x_1)/x_0^e \cdot x_1^n/1 \in \mathcal{O}_X(n)(D_+(x_1))$, with $F, G$ homogeneous of degree d, e, resp. We may assume that $F$ is not divisable by $x_0$, and similar for $G$. Then saying that their restrictions on the intersection are the same is equivalent to $F/x_0^d \cdot (x_0/x_1)^n = G/x_1^e.$ Here we must have $d \leq n$. This says that $F/x_0^d \in k[x_{0/1}]$ has degree $d \leq n$. Conversely for an element of $k[x_{0/1}]$ of degree $\leq n$, one gets $F$ and $G$, and $f$ and $g$, hence a global section.

Thus a global section of $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ naturally correspond to an element of $k[x_{0/1}]$ of degree $\leq n$. In other words, an element of $k[x_{0/1}]/(x_{0/1}^{n+1})$.

(2) Consider a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\phi:\mathcal{O}_X(n) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$. On $D(x_i)$ it corresponds to a linear map of $k[x_{j/i}]$-modules $\phi_{D(x_i)} : k[x_{j/i}] \cdot x_i^n/1 \rightarrow k[x_{j/i}]$. We let $f_i = \phi_{D(x_i)}(x_i^n/1).$

Since on $U = D_+(x_0) \cap D_+(x_1)$, $(x_0^n/1)|U = x_{0/1}^n|U \cdot (x_1^n/1)|U$, we have $f_0|U = \phi_U(x_0^n/1) = \phi_{D_+(x_1)}(x_{0/1}^n \cdot (x_1^n/1))|U = x_{0/1}^n|U \, f_1|U.$

If we write $f_i = F_i(x_0, x_1)/x_i^{d_i}$ with $F_i$ homogeneous of degree $d_i$ and not divisable by $x_i$, then we the equation is $F_0/x_0^{d_0} = (x_0/x_1)^n \cdot F_1/x_1^{d_1}$. From this, since $n>0$, we must have $F_0 = 0$ and similarly $F_1 = 0$. Now $\phi = 0$.

(3) Yes, that is right. The global sections of $\mathcal{O}_Y(n)$ corresponds to polynomials of $k[x_{j/i}]_{j\neq i}$ of degree $\leq n$ and the dimension is $\binom{m+n}{m}$.

Another way to see this is to regard $\mathcal{O}_Y(n)(D_+(x_i))$ and $\mathcal{O}_Y(n)(D_+(x_ix_j))$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded algebra $k[x_0, x_0^{-1}, \cdots, x_m, x_m^{-1}]$. Then the restriction maps are just the inclusion maps and $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y(n)) = \bigcap_i k[x_j/x_i] \cdot x_i^n/1 = k[x_0, x_0^{-1}, \cdots, x_m, x_m^{-1}]_n$. This is even true if $n < 0$ or $k$ is any ring.